# In-Call voip status bar in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

We are currently developing an app that uses peer-to-peer audio/voice transfer through APIs. When the app is in the background, a message appears in the in-call status bar reading “XXX (Recording)”.  If we remove the in-call status bar altogether the voice goes to mute when the app is in the background. Apparently this message comes from Apple because it doesn’t appear in Android Samsung devices. We would like to change the content and perhaps the color of the in-call status bar in order to remove the word “Recording”. Please refer to attached screen shot. So any advice on the in-call status bar modification? Skype for example has its costume VoIP status bar

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot hide or customize the recording bar.
iOS chooses the colors and text of the bar depending on what you are doing:

**Recordings** are red, which is what you are doing.
**Calls** are green, which is what Skype is doing.
**AirPlay** and **Personal hotspot** are blue.

If you want the same color as Skype try changing your [UIBackgroundModes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) to "voip" (or maybe look if you need to be using [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit)?)

Comment: Voice Memos' red status bar shows the elapsed time instead of the application's name, but I guess they are able to do this because it is an Apple product and they are using non-public APIs?

Answer (score 3):

Modifying  recording bar (Color-text or anything) is **NOT POSSIBLE** in ios.

Hiding this when you are using Microphone is also  **NOT POSSIBLE**. This bar appear as long as you use mic. Recoding or not, if mic is in use, It will display this bar. Its security measure for users to know that an app is listening to microphone.

Comment: Can I add a bar above or something like that

Comment: No, you cant do it when your app is in background.

Comment: but how skype has its own voip bar

Comment: @AMH it will show up when you turn on the microphone for your voip call